# Comparision between semi, quasi and linear partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

Are the followings right?

- Any linear PDE is semi linear (pseudo-linear) PDE.
- Any semi-linear PDE (Pseudo-linear) is quasi-linear PDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, since in the following list,

- linear
- pseudo-linear (which I suppose is the same I know as semi-linear)
- quasi-linear

each item is a generalization of the ones above it.

Comment: That's much better. Thanks. Also, the answer could be further improved if you add a few words about the definitions of the phrases "semilinear" and "quasilinear" making it clear that each item is a generalization of the one above.